# How to reference Photoshop Folder object in VBScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, automation, photoshop-script

Using [Adobe PhotoShop CS4 scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html), JavaScript provides the `File` and `Folder` classes, but I do not see how I can use these classes from VBScript.

Currently I use the `DoJavaScript` function like this:

```
Set appRef = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")
jsCode = Array(_
    "var inFolder = Folder.selectDialog('Select a folder to process');",_
    "if(inFolder != null){",_
    "  var fileList = inFolder.getFiles(/\.(jpg|jpeg|tif|)$/i);",_
    "  var outFolder = new Folder(decodeURI(inFolder) + '/Edited');",_
    "  if (outFolder.exists == false) outFolder.create();",_
    "  for(var i = 0 ;i < fileList.length; i++){",_
    "    var doc = open(fileList[i]);",_
    "    doc.flatten();",_
    "    var docName = fileList[i].name.slice(0,-4);",_
    "    var saveFile = new File(decodeURI(outFolder) + '/' + docName + '.png');",_
    "    SavePNG(saveFile);",_
    "    activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);",_
    "  }",_
    "}",_
    "function SavePNG(saveFile){",_
    "  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();",_
    "  pngSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;",_
    "  pngSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;",_
    "  pngSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;",_
    "  pngSaveOptions.quality = 1;",_
    "  pngSaveOptions.PNG8 = false;",_
    "  pngSaveOptions.transparency = true;",_
    "  activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);",_
    "}")
appRef.DoJavaScript(Join(jsCode, vbNewLine))
```

My question is: **Can I use the `Folder` and `File` classes directly from my VB script?**
Something like:

```
Set psFolder = appRef.Folder
inputFolder  = psFolder.selectDialog("Select a folder to process")
```

When I try this, `appRef.Folder` returns this error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Quick question: Is **Adobe Photoshop CS5** the library you are using?

Comment: I want to make sure that I am looking at the correct library before commenting incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I forget to say that, `CS4`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question. The `Folder` object is **specifically meant for Javascript, but this is in VBScript.** The `Folder` object will not be available with the CS4 library. To use this object, you must find it in **a Javascript library for VBScript.** Otherwise, neither VBS or CS4 have these.

Comment: @s0d4pop The example script I posted works with CS4, but if I get right your response, I can't access directly `Folder` (or `File`) object in VBScript?

Comment: The `Folder` and `File` objects don't exist in VBScript, as they are meant for Javascript. However, there are other ways for VBScript to access folders and dialogs.

Comment: I see, by "other ways for VBScript to access folders and dialogs" did you mean VBScript native functions like `Shell.Application.BrowseForFolder` or some `Photoshop` dialogues?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking. However, I have never tried it(For Shell Object).

Answer (score 0):

In VBscript, you can access folder with the FileSystemObject:

```
'1.a - user browse for folder
Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select Folder", 0, myStartFolder )
'1.b - or use a fixed one
sFolder = "C:\foo\anyFolder\"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = fs.GetFolder(sFolder)

'parse the content of the folder
Set oChildren = objFolder.SubFolders
ReDim aList(oChildren.Count)
For i = 1 To oChildren.Count
    aList(i) = oChildren.Item(i).Name
Next
```